# Ropsten network connection with web3.js(Version 1.0.0-beta.34)

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I have an serious issue, I'm trying to figure out since two days but not succeeded.
I want to connect testnet ropsten using web3.js which I guess I'm successful but issue is I have some balance on ropsten network but web3.js displaying only 0.

You can check my address here it has some test 4.999873784 Ether:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x0346d2e50E29065b3b3c73B878FaFDcEb8Ee13f0

Here I will describe my flow (all links and ips are fake):

1. First started geth

   ```
   geth --testnet --networkid 3 --rpc --rpcaddr "36.241.154.2" --rpccorsdomain "shahzad.com, http://shahzad.com, https://shahzad..com" --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal, account"
   ```
2. I included web3.js in my web page.

   ```
   //https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js
   <script src="http://shahzad.com/myapp/web3.js-1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   //var Web3 = require('web3');
   var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://36.241.154.2'))

   $(function(){

   web3.eth.getBalance('0x0346d2e50E29065b3b3c73B878FaFDcEb8Ee13f0' , function(err, res){
       console.log("getBalance: "+res); //Displaying 0 //https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x0346d2e50E29065b3b3c73B878FaFDcEb8Ee13f0

   });
   web3.eth.net.getId(function(err, res){
           console.log("Net: "+res); //Displaying 3
   });
   web3.eth.net.getNetworkType(function(err, res){
           console.log("getNetworkType: "+res); //Displaying ropsten
   });  
   web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function(error, result){
       console.log("Block Number: "+result); // Displaying 0
   })
   });
   ```

Additional steps taken:

```
eth.syncing
{
 currentBlock: 3069355,
 highestBlock: 3069421,
 knownStates: 27609511,
 pulledStates: 27597775,
 startingBlock: 3069303

}
```

What is wrong here any clue will be really appreciated.

Comment: Your balance shows up correctly on my node, so your issue must be either with your node or with the `HttpProvider`. A couple things to try 1) confirm your connecting to the correct provider by outputting a debug call to `web3.eth.currentProvider` before your call to `getBalance`. 2) Are you using port 80 (or is this just part of your masking of IPs)? You don't have `--rpcport` specified and the default is 8545. 3) Does the correct network id show up in your console when you start `geth` (you don't need both `--networkid` and `--testnet`. Just use `--testnet`)?

Comment: @AdamKipnis thank you, the issue was with my node it was not fully synced with so now I have equal number of currentBlock and highestBlock, can you please change your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The balance was showing up correctly through my local node and MetaMask, indicating an issue with OP's node. OP indicated via comments that once the node was fully synced (`currentBlock == highestBlock`), balance was showing correctly.

Note that in the post, the `currentBlock` was past the point where the transactions occurred, but the balance didn't show until fully synced. This is likely due to the state trie not yet being synced.